# Habilitar VT-x en sony vaio

Tags: permisos

Tengo un portátil sony vaio modelo SVF142C29U con soporte para VT-x (Virtualización). El problema es que por defecto viene deshabilitado por sony y en la BIOS no me aparece ninguna opción para habilitarlo. Necesito habilitar VT-x para poder trabajar ya que trabajo con virtualización.
¿Alguien sabe cómo habilitarlo?

Comment: Has probado instalar `SecurAble` para comprobar si es 100% compatible? https://www.grc.com/securable.htm , según tengo entendido se activa desde la BIOS, otra opción sería probar y descargar la última versión del driver de la BIOS.

Comment: Apaga la laptop
Presiona boton Assist
Presiona F2
Habilita Virtualizacion
Listo.